# Move from Jersey 1.x to Jersey 2.x - NoSuchMethod error

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

I moved from Jersey 1.19 to Jersey 2.27. I get an error relate dto Guava. I wonder how guava is related.
This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gr.iti.sodalite</groupId>
    <artifactId>semantic-reasoner</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>reasoning-engine</module>
        <module>reasoner-api</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <jersey2.version>2.27</jersey2.version>
        <jaxrs.version>2.1.1</jaxrs.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
        <!-->dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet -->
        <!-- dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency-->
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdf4j-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
             <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>rdf4j-sparqlbuilder</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>3.0.0</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ontotext.graphdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphdb-free-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>reasoner-api</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                     <!--  configuration>
                 <source>8</source>
                 <javadocExecutable>${java.home}/bin/javadoc</javadocExecutable> 
                </configuration-->
                
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

My web.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <!-- For Jersey 1.x -->
        <!-- servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class-->
        <!-- For Jersey 2.x -->
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>            
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                io.swagger.jaxrs.json,
                io.swagger.jaxrs.listing,
                restapi
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v0.6/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The web application is running on tomcat 9. When I deploy the reasoner.war file on the webapps folder, and I start the application, I get those errors:

Focus on:
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService**

```
> Nov 20, 2020 2:47:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
> log SEVERE: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw
> exception MultiException stack 1 of 2 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()'
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerExecutorsFactory$2.getRespondingExecutor(ServerExecutorsFactory.java:89)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.ExecutorsFactory.getInitialRespondingExecutor(ExecutorsFactory.java:126)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerExecutorsFactory.<init>(ServerExecutorsFactory.java:85)
>   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
>   at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
>   at
> org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1092)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:261)
>   at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:336)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:118)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2296)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:556)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
>   at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:792)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:797)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:870)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:862)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:484)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:161)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:286)
>   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)  at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:283)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:283)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
>   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4872)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1848)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
> MultiException stack 2 of 2 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
> perform operation: create on
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerExecutorsFactory    at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:363)     at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:118)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2296)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:556)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
>   at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:792)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:797)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:870)
>   at
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:862)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:484)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:161)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:286)
>   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)  at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:283)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:283)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
>   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4872)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1848)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
> 
> Nov 20, 2020 2:47:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
> loadOnStartup SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web
> application [/reasoner-api] threw load() exception
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()'
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerExecutorsFactory$2.getRespondingExecutor(ServerExecutorsFactory.java:89)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.ExecutorsFactory.getInitialRespondingExecutor(ExecutorsFactory.java:126)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerExecutorsFactory.<init>(ServerExecutorsFactory.java:85)
>   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)
```

**Question:** Any idea about how to solve those errors?

Answer (score 0):

For migrating from Jersey 1.x to Jersey 2.x, I solved the issue by adding the following dependencies to the pom.xml. Also, since I use java 11, Jersey >=2.27 version should be used.

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
        <jersey2.version>2.32</jersey2.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
...

<build>
        <finalName>reasoner-api</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
</plugins>
...
```